# Why is there no color in the overlay?

Tags: tropico-4

How it's supposed to look like:
[image: How it's supposed to look like]

How mine looks like:
[image: Mine]

I can't view any color on my overlay; what would be the problem?

Comment: Can you specify? I see colors in that screenshot. Can you perhaps post a screenshot (from the net) that show how you want it to look?

Comment: in corp overlay mode, there should be green and red indicating the fertility, but instead, mine only shows white and grey,

Answer (score 4):

You most likely have colorblind mode on.
So turn off colorblind mode from general settings.

Comment: love you, bro!!